# Form submit not working when using magento secure url for action

Tags: php, magento

I have a from that when submit runs a little php to export data to a csv.  The php looks like :

```
$out = '';
if (isset($_POST['csv_hdr'])) {
$out .= $_POST['csv_hdr'];
$out .= "\n";
}

if (isset($_POST['csv_text'])) {
$out .= $_POST['csv_text'];
}

$filename = "z_".date("Y-n-d",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-n-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $out;
exit;
```

This works fine if I do a normal path to the php file like :

```
<form name="export"  action="http://website.com/getcsv.php"  method="post">
```

I am trying to move this php function into a controller now and call it that way.  I am working on a magento admin module so I have to pass the url with the security key.  So I move that function into an action in the controller :

```
public function getcsvAction(){
    $out = '';
    ...
}
```

Then I am able to get the url with something like :

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("module/index/getcsv/");?>
```

This gives me a link with the key like :

```
http://website.com/module/index/getcsv/key/7431c859914c40d3f66dfcd1530813b3/
```

If I paste that link into the browser it executes the php fine.  However when I replace it in my form action it no longer works and just does a redirect to the dashboard.  I can not see any errors output and I am not sure what is happening.  Any ideas on how to get this POST to work using a secure path as the action?

Comment: Are you sure you arent' simply hitting a `404`?

Comment: Yes PeeHaa I grabbed the url from the action and pasted it in the browser and it worked ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it thanks to [this post](http://www.spinonesolutions.com/2011/01/admin-form-post-form_key/).

I needed to add this to the form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<? echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is missing the adminhtml area. Try this:

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("*/module/index/getcsv/");
```

Comment: Thanks but no that is not it. When I look at what is output in the action it is correct url.  If I use your code I get something like /module/module and I get a 404